# Having trouble finding and uninstalling local solc versions to enable solc-select

Tags: solc, compiler, macos

Years ago, I used Homebrew to install `ethereum` and `solidity`. Lately, I've been trying to use `solc-select`, but as its documentation states, it doesn't work when there's a local copy of `solc` already installed from Homebrew.

So I used Homebrew to uninstall `solidity`, and I confirmed that the `solc` binary in `/usr/local/bin/` is gone. Nonetheless, my global version is stuck at v0.5.15, and attempting to compile anything results in the error you'd expect to see when using the wrong compiler version:

```
ParserError: Source file requires different compiler version (current compiler is 0.5.15+commit.6a57276f.Darwin.clang - note that nightly builds are considered to be strictly less than the released version
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;
^---------------------^
```

I've wasted more time than I'm proud to admit trying to figure out where this phantom `solc` version is living on my machine. How can I get rid of it and let `solc-select` take over?

I should mention that I have of course already installed `solc-select`, used it to add new versions, and used it to switch the current version to 0.8.0. I'm fairly certain it's configured properly, and that my problem is coming from this old version of `solc` (0.5.15) still hiding somewhere in the depths of my machine.

**SOLVED**:
Of course, I managed to find it shortly after pleading for help online. For anyone else who may run into this, the mystery `solc` was living in my nix profile. After deleting it, I then had to uninstall and reinstall `solc-select`, and I'm finally good to go.